# HopperBulletEnv Environment does not exist

Tags: openai-gym

I am executing the following line in Google Colab:

```
import gym 
env = gym.make("HopperBulletEnv-v0")
```

But I get the error that the environment does not exist. Did they changed the name of the environment? Do somebody know if there is an alternative or what could I use/do instead ?
I could not find any solution in the net.

best regards